# knockout style binding not working ie8

Tags: binding, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, styles

I am using Knockout.js and I have the following binding to add spacing (margin-left).

```
<div class="editor-field" data-bind="style : { 'margin-left' : ($root.getHierarchyLevel($index()) * 30 + 'px')}">
```

This works in IE9 and IE8 compatibility mode. But when I run the same code in IE8 on Windows XP, I do not see any spacing.

I created a jsfiddle example. This add spacing before blah in IE9 but not in IE8.

Any ideas??

Comment: This could be due to differences in IE8's rendering, and not a problem adding it. Did you check to see if the style was on the element?

Comment: Yes..it is. <div class="editor-field" style="margin-left: 30px;" sizset="false" data-bind="style : { 'margin-left' : ($root.getHierarchyLevel($index()) * 30 + 'px')}" sizcache0007085005770362418="199 134 76" __ko__1352780051687="ko457">

Comment: Yea, its not really knockouts job to make IE8 render css to spec. That kind of sucks though.

Answer (score 5):

From: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

"If you want to apply a font-weight or text-decoration style, or any other style whose name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g., because it contains a hyphen), you must use the JavaScript name for that style."

Try this instead:

`<div class="editor-field" data-bind="style : { 'marginLeft' : ($root.getHierarchyLevel($index()) * 30 + 'px')}">`

Answer (score 2):

For people having the same issue, I had to use css binding to get this to work. We cann also directly add "class" binding as part of attr.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change, as it was not working in IE8

```
<div data-bind="style: { display: $data.items.isLoading() ? 'flex' : 'none' }">
```

to

```
<div data-bind="css: { 'searchLoaderFlex' :  $data.items.isLoading(), 'searchLoaderGone':  !$data.items.isLoading() }">
```

or

```
<div data-bind="css: $data.items.isLoading() == true ? 'searchLoaderFlex' : 'searchLoaderGone'">
```